# How to clear MSIE/WinInet cache programmatically?

Tags: winapi, caching, wininet

I'm trying to clear out the WinInet cache using Win32 API - by invalidating the cache entries, or deleting them (doesn't matter). I can't find any way to do this for the whole cache (other than iterating over each entry - [example in C#](http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/46049-How-delete-my-temporary-internet-files.aspx), [another in VB](http://www.vbforums.com/archive/index.php/t-440508.html)) - is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly certain doing the FindFirst/FindNextUrlCacheEntry() then DeleteUrlCacheEntry() is the only way to make sure it works across all versions of IE.

Alternatively you can use FindFirst/[FindNextUrlCacheGroup()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384126(VS.85).aspx) and [DeleteUrlCacheGroup()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383990(VS.85).aspx) with "CACHEGROUP_FLAG_FLUSHURL_ONDELETE" but you have to make sure you only delete what you want.  For example, history, cookies and temporary internet files are all Cache groups.

Comment: In this case, I wouldn't mind deleting all those. Was hoping that there was an easier way; oh well.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, it is possible to (ab)use the Internet Options panel to clear the cache files by executing this:

```
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8
```

Will try to call this as a DLL.

Source: http://www.vbforums.com/archive/index.php/t-440508.html , comment by technorobbo

Answer (score 2):

Do not use the method:  RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8
This is unsupported by Microsoft and has been shown to break the cache and cause all sorts of unusual problems.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think this would still be relevant in 2019, but here we are :)

Answer (score 0):

FTR: The exact meaning of the argument (8 above, means only Temporary Internet Files and not Cookies etc.) is explained e.g. on http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/clear-ie7-browsing-history-from-the-command-line.

BTW: Unfortunately RunDll32 is asynchronous, which makes it not ideal for running before e.g. automated web tests. Would anybody have an idea either how to run this as a blocking call, or to how to programmatically find the exact directory name of the "Temporary Internet Files" directory so it can be polled until empty? Code it in C (need it in Java, could do JNI) is really the only option, huh? ;(

PS: How can one post a reply to an existing answer instead of starting a new answer on stackoverflow?

Comment: Thanks, the bit-mask is indeed relevant in the call. (and btw, when you reach reputation 50, you'll be able to leave comments on other people's questions and answers; until then, you can only comment on your own)