# extract cab file and execute the exe file(inside the cab file) automatically

Tags: extract, exe, execute, cab

I have a cab file(w/ an executable file inside) embedded on my webpage. When the user access the page the cab file will be automatically extracted and the executable file inside should be executed as well. Is this possible? My hunch is that this will be configured in my inf file but I don't know how. I would appreciate your help in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the hook&run values, like in [this sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751974(VS.85).aspx#EXAMPLE)

> ```
> [version]  
> signature="$CHICAGO$"  
> AdvancedINF=2.0  
>
> [Add.Code]  
> time.ocx=time.ocx  
> msvcrt.dll=msvcrt.dll    
> mfc42.dll=mfc42.dll  
> olepro32.dll=olepro32.dll  
>
> [time.ocx]  
> file-win32-x86=thiscab  
> clsid={DCF0768D-BA7A-101A-B57A-0000C0C3ED5F}  
> FileVersion=1,0,0,0  
> RegisterServer=yes  
>
> [msvcrt.dll]  
> FileVersion=4,20,0,6164  
> hook=mfc42installer  
>
> [mfc42.dll]  
> FileVersion=4,2,0,6256  
> hook=mfc42installer 
>
> [olepro32.dll]  
> FileVersion=4,2,0,6068  
> hook=mfc42installer
>
> [mfc42installer]  
> file-win32-x86=http://activex.microsoft.com/controls/vc/mfc42.cab  
> run=%EXTRACT_DIR%\mfc42.exe
> ```

Comment: thanks shay. I knew it would be on the inf file hehe!If you don't mind I would like to make a follow question. I checked my temporary internet files and I can see the cab file I downloaded. Is it possible to delete it on the cache after the exe is executed? Sorry for being too ignorant.

Comment: It's Ok, I don't know in which state the cab is while running the exe.  take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825144/how-to-clear-msie-wininet-cache-programatically