# windows mobile cab file launch main executable when complete

Tags: windows-mobile, installation, cab, autorun

I am developing a WinMo app, where we are hosting the cab files on our web server, to make deployment to our handhelds easier.

I would like to make the CAB file though, so that when they user downloads and runs it, it installs, and then automatically launches the program.

I found [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062550/extract-cab-file-and-execute-the-exe-fileinside-the-cab-file-automatically), but that seems to be about cabs for ActiveX browser addins or such.

Anyone have any idea or instructions on how to go about making a WinMo CAB autoinstall the primary output file after installation? I am building the CAB file using the Smart Device CAB Setup project in Visual Studio 2008. The devices are WinMo 6.1.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4):

I am currently working on Windows Mobile 6.1 handheld devices. I had the same issue to be solved and fortunately I was able to solve this issue. Please follow these guidelines carefully.

```
       * You had to have create an XML script if you have multiple CAB files
       * If you have a single CAB file than place your cab file in CABFOLDER on your
         mobile unit and run AUTOCAB.EXE that can be found somewhere in your mobile unit
       * If you want to work with XML script than follow this XML

enter code here
```

---

```
 '<AutoConfig>
 <Files>



<File Src="http://10.0.0.102/Softwares/XMLMultiFileDownload.zip"
    Dest="\SD Card\XMLMulti12eDownload.zip"
    FileId="620.121.0">
</File>

<File Src="http://10.0.0.102/Softwares/hello.zip"
    Dest="\SD Card\29Sep.zip"
    FileId="530.0.04">
</File>

<File Src="http://10.0.0.102/Softwares/IBI.CAB" 
    Dest="\CabFiles\IBI.CAB"
    FileId="130.331.151.1521"
StartIn="\CabFiles"     
Run="\CabFiles\autocab.exe"
    CmdLine="-FILE=&quot;\CabFiles\IBI.CAB&quot; -FORCE -SHOW=2 -CHKRST=1">
Wait="true"
</File>  

<File Src="http://10.0.0.102/Softwares/DC_Net.CAB" 
          Dest="\Flash File Store\DC_Net.CAB"
          FileId="125.734.03.0390"
          Run="\2577\autocab.exe"
         CmdLine="-FILE=&quot;\Flash File Store\DC_Net.CAB&quot; -FORCE -SHOW=2-
      Wait="false"
     >
  </File>

 </Files>
 </AutoConfig>  '
```

---

```
enter code here
```

Note: this file must be a standard XML format

Answer (score 3):

To be clear, what you have now is that the CAB downloads and installs properly, but what you want is for the application to execute after the install completes?  If that's the case, then add a [custom setup DLL](http://www.cnblogs.com/pengai3/archive/2008/10/23/1317391.html) that does the execute on successful completion (so in Install_Exit call CreateProcess).

Comment: Yes, that is what I have, and am looking to do. Is that article still relevant - technically speaking? I had thought eVC (and eVB) had been discontinued. Even clicking the link in the article to developer tools seems to go to a page that talks all about Visual Studio 2005 (also dated now).

Comment: The code is still very relevant.  Yes, the eVC tool is discontinued, but the C++ language is still very much alive.  Just create the DLL using a Studio 2005 or 2008 C++ Smart Device project.

Comment: Cool! I know C++ is still around - I can't imagine that disappearing anytime soon; but I didn't know if eVC has lots of other stuff added in, or what not. Thanks for the info, I will definitely have to give this a try.