# Enable C# to clear cookies in IE7

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-7

How do I modify IE7 to allow my application to clear the cookies?

WatiN has a clearcookies() method that don't work because of IE's security.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work because of IE's security? It works just fine; I use it every day.

Comment: You could just delete the files in the temp folder :o)

Comment: Ian P, do you allow your application to delete the cookies? Or do you mean manually deleting them?

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825144/how-to-clear-msie-wininet-cache-programatically

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this would be through a command-line call. Something like:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
// ...
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2");
```

Warning, untested. Also, if you're on Vista or newer, you might run into permissions grief.